# How to organize Webpack 5 files for different modes with same plugins

Tags: webpack

### Some context:

I have been told by coworkers that the new version of Webpack handles the configuration in different files: *webpack.development.config.js*, *webpack.production.config.js*... (and you can even create custom modes). But they didn't know how the explain the whole thing. Only that now everything is done with multiple config files.

From the [official docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/), I see that the different modes have a comment on the top stating different file names:

**Development**

```
// webpack.development.config.js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
};
```

**Production**

```
// webpack.production.config.js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
};
```

So there must be some truth in this and I want to follow best practices. It seems logic that keeping config for different modes separate is a good thing to do.

But I don't know how I should correctly load plugins now.

I used to have this at the top of my files:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const WatchTimePlugin = require('webpack-watch-time-plugin');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const webpack = require('webpack');
```

So, this ends up leaving me with the following questions.

### Questions

Do I still need a global config file for Webpack? If there isn't any global config file, how can I have common tasks that I want to run both for production and development?

Does webpack load all files called webpack.xxxxxx.config.js? Can I just create whatever config files I like with that name and it will take them all into consideration?

How can I achieve common config for dev and prod, and then special extended config for dev and prod?

I find that the documentation isn't really clear about all this. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the plugin, for example, `HtmlWebpackPlugin` injects scripts and styles into html templates. That's something you need in both development and production builds.
`MinicssExtractPlugin` on the other hand extracts CSS into seperate files, something you may not need in development.
I suggest that you get a pen and paper, visit each plugin's website and decide if the plugin:

- Is (or can be) used both in development and production
- Is used only in development (`react-refresh-webpack-plugin` for example)
- Is used only in production (I put `MiniCssExtractPlugin` here)

Then in the config:

```js
// webpack.shared.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        // Shared plugins
    ]
};
```

```js
// webpack.development.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        // Dev only plugins
    ]
};
```

```js
// webpack.production.config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        // Prod only plugins
    ]
};
```

A good way of organizing plugins is:

1. Does it improve the user experience (loading time, usage)? Production
2. Is it necessary for the app to work? Shared
3. Does it help in development? Development

> Does webpack load all files called webpack.xxxxxx.config.js? Can I just create whatever config files I like with that name and it will take them all into consideration?

Webpack automatically (if the config is not specified in the command line) loads only one file named `webpack.config.js`. If it doesn't exist then it uses a default config.
You should always specify the config file used:

```
npx webpack --config config/webpack.config.js
```

I suggest you do the following to separate development and production configuration:

```bash
npm install webpack-merge --save-dev
# or
yarn add webpack-merge --dev
```

Directory structure:

```
src
|__ package.json
|__ config
    |__ webpack.shared-config.js
    |__ webpack.dev-config.js
    |__ webpack.prod-config.js
```

```js
// webpack.shared.config.js
module.exports = {
    // Configuration to be used in both modes, `entry` goes here
};
```

```js
// webpack.dev-config.js
let { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(require("./webpack.shared-config.js"), {
    mode: "development",
    // Other dev only config
});
```

```js
// webpack.prod-config.js
let { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(require("./webpack.shared-config.js"), {
    mode: "production",
    // Other production only config
});
```

Then you can specify the config file in the webpack cli:

```bash
# To build in development mode
npx webpack --config config/webpack.dev-config.js
# or, in production
npx webpack --config config/webpack.prod-config.js
```

Additionally, you can add a build (and serve) scripts to `package.json`:

```json
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod-config.js",
        "build-dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev-config.js",
        "serve": "webpack serve --hmr --config config/webpack.dev-config.js",
        "serve-prod": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.prod-config.js",
    }
    // ...
}
```

Notes:

1. `webpack serve` requires `webpack-dev-server` to be installed:

```bash
npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev
# or
yarn add webpack-dev-server --dev
```

2. `webpack-merge` does a deep merge:

```js
let a = {
    b: {
        c: [1]
    }
};

console.log(
    merge(a, {
        b: {
            c: [2]
        }
    })
);
// Outputs:
// {
//   b: {
//     c: [1, 2]
//   }
// }
```

3. Merged object doesn't necessarily need to be a webpack config, it can be anything.

Also see:

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/
- https://dev.to/marcinwosinek/tutorial-for-building-multipage-website-with-webpack-4gdk (<3)

Comment: This gives me some really interesting insight. Thanks a lot. There is one missing piece of information. Does webpack load all files called webpack.xxxxxx.config.js? So, I can just create whatever config files I like with that name and it will take them all into consideration?

Comment: Please edit your question because the answer better be an answer not a comment